# TYPO3 4.7 + "indexed search" wont work

Tags: search, typo3

I've installed the extension "Indexed Search" in a TYPO3 4.7 installation, but it won't work. When I add the plugin in a column, the "Starting point" field wont come.

I thought I could set it up with typoscript, so I added this to the template:

```
page.config.index_enable = 1
plugin.tx_indexedsearch{
    show{
        advancedSearchLink = 0
        rules = 0
        alwaysShowPageLinks = 1
    }
    search{
        rootPidList = 1
        skipExtendToSubpagesChecking = 1
    }
    view.defaultPid = 81
    result_link_target = 81
}
```

But it isnt indexing anything yet. What should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it! I had to activate the cache!

```
config.no_cache = 0
```

Comment: Indexed search works only on cached page. Something is wrong with your configuration.

Comment: no_cache = 0 means "caching pages" :D I know it sounds like a doble negation. The Syntaxis is not very good :D

Comment: But you wrote I had to deactivate the cache. This isn't a double negation.